# Should I use Magento 2 pre alpha already for production shops?

Tags: magento2

I know, it is alpha software, but at least there are lots of tests and bugfixes which are not in Magento 1.

- If I write own modules for Magento 2, is the module structure very likely to change?
- Are the core functionalities we have in Magento 1 already functional in Magento 2?

Comment: Echoing the answers below:  1. No;  2. If you ever have a question "Should I run this in production" where you're unsure of the answer, it's No;  3. Magento 2 is a work in progress, and the architecture is shifting from release to release. Stick with Magento 1 for the time being.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is only valid for pre-release Magento 2 version. More info here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 9):

No, Magento 2 just isn't ready for it.
I recently checked it out and installed it but there is very much styling missing in the backend and everything is still subject to change.

I tried developing a module but finding documentation on it was difficult and many tutorials are outdated.

I would recommend waiting at least another year before you can properly use Magento 2 on a live environment. Right now they still seem to be defining Magento and transfering everything to jQuery. Also expect Magento to be buggy on it's initial release.
If you look at the history of Magento 1 you can see how long it takes to have it stable and reasonably fast.

However I do suggest you install Magento 2 just to have a look at what's changed in the structure.

Also I don't completely agree with some of the changes they've made, for example assigning products to categories. They got rid of the tree and now they have a text field that auto completes when typing the category name (like the tags on stackexchange). I would rather use the tree to navigate to a category to make sure I got the right one. It is, however, quicker to use as opposed to the tree.

**EDIT**

> If I write own modules for Magento 2, is the module structure very
>   likely to change?

I would say there is a chance of them changing it, nothing that should stop you from developing a module though.

> Are the core functionalities we have in Magento 1 already functional
>   in Magento 2?

I haven't checked this but because of the transfer to jQuery and the changes they've made to the core there may be bugs.

Comment: Sorry Rick, but you have not answered none of two questions of OP.

Comment: @Tim I actually answered 1 of 3 questions the OP had :P And I edited my post to partly answer the other 2.

Comment: Sorry Rick. Nothing personal. Just tried to improve your answer. ;-)

Comment: @Tim Didn't take it personal, I appreciate the fact you strive for quality answers :-)

Comment: And I thought the Swiss were so nice.

Comment: @benmarks he is not Swiss. Sorry Tim :-)

Comment: @SylvainRayé: i kill you!

Answer (score 4):

- It is not possible to give a discrete answer to the question like this. I bet even M2 team itself is not able to say what code will stay and what will go. From what I see right now if you start developing extensions for M2 right away they will most likely work with the final release but you may miss some new cool stuff.

  For instance even though `getModel()`-like factories will be deprecated you still will be able to use them as the backward compatibility will be persevered. Nevertheless you still can't use `getModel()`'s replacement as this code is still under constructions and will be heavily refactored. Same with other stuff.
- This really depends on what can be called `core` functionality. If you mean if catalog/checkout/customer modules are there and working, the answer is "Yes". However everything is still under modifications and much dependent on new stuff they are injecting right now (e.g. partial ZF2 integration, jQuery, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to reiterate Rick's comments.  In no way should Magento2 be used in a production environment. I would say that even when it moves into a stable release it would be a good idea to wait for a bit before deploying live as there are bound to be issues that need fixes to be applied.

Comment: Same as Rick. What about extension structure in M2? What about core functionality?

Comment: Fair enough Tim.  I suppose I should have put it as a comment to Rick's original answer rather than a separate answer although it did answer the main subject post I think.